# Is there a way to return nil message to user but not interrupt the app in ruby?

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I'm trying to find a way to write in GUI for user that there is nothing in the button they just clicked

I've tried a method like `

```
if @album[@user_choice_album].tracks[10].name == nil
                return
```

`
But it interrupt the program and gave an message instead, while i was expecting it to interrupt the procedure and go to the next one.

```
test.rb:192:in `draw_now_playing': undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

            if (!(@album[@user_choice_album].tracks[10].name))\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have `tracks` stored in an array (without knowing any details about your data structure and model). And when the user requests a track that doesn't exist, it returns `nil`.

That means there is no point in asking if the `name` of that track is `nil` when the whole `track` is `nil`.

I guess this should work for you:

```
if @album[@user_choice_album].tracks[10].nil?
  return
```

Or simplified:

```
return unless @album[@user_choice_album].tracks[10]
```